# If $|z|>2$ then $-f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{z=2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Here is my question:  Suppose $f$ is analytic in the region $\{z:|z|>1\}$ and that $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}f(z)=0$.  Show that if $|z|>2$ then $-f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{z=2}\frac{f(\zeta}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$.

My thoughts were that if $|z|<2$ then the integral would just equal $f(z)$ by Cauchy's formula since $z$ would lie within the contour. So, since our $z$ lies outside of the contour, then the sign on the integral would be reversed (now that I type this, I am not sure if I can claim this...).  On the other hand, I wouldn't be using  the given assumptions, so I am thinking that the problem requires a bit more than this.  Maybe I could try and use some radius of convergence stuff? Any thoughts, suggestions, ideas, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: An easy way is to use the Laurent series of $f$ and show that $a_k=0, k \ge 0$ because of the limit at infinity and then expand $1/(\zeta-z)$ and do the integral term by term by absolute convergence on the circle $|z|=2$

Comment: If $|z|<2$ then you can't claim that the integral is equal to $f(z)$ because $\zeta=z$ may be not the only singularity of the integrand inside $|z|=2$; in fact, the behavior of the integrand inside $|z|=1$ is not even known. (Actually the integral is equal to $0$ in this case, by the very same reasoning as in the solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R>|z|>2.$ Then by the residue theorem, $$\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}~d\zeta-\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}~d\zeta=f(z).$$ By the residue theorem again, $$\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}~d\zeta=\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=R_1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}~d\zeta$$ for any $R_1>R.$ Now $$\left|\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=R_1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}~d\zeta\right|\leq \frac{2\pi R_1}{2\pi(R_1-|z|)}\max_{|\zeta|=R_1}|f(\zeta)|$$ tends to $0$ as $R_1\rightarrow \infty.$ It follows that $$-\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=2}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}~d\zeta=f(z),$$ hence the result.

Comment: Thank you!  Just a quick question: What is the purpose of $R_1$ coming into play?   For instance, why couldn't we have just used the 3rd equation for $|\zeta|=R$ instead of needing to first consider $|\zeta|=R_1$?

Comment: The idea is to replace the integral over $|\zeta|=R$ by that over $|\zeta|=R_1$ (the two must be equal, as the function is analytic in between). To prove that it is zero, just let $R_1\rightarrow \infty$. Yes, you can just let $R\rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Okay, thank you!!